# New Core Foundation leak in xCode5

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, core-foundation

xCode5 is citing a new `CoreText` leak that I didn't see in the previous versions of xCode. I have the following code:

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFMutableAttributedStringRef)self.text);
CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddRect(mutablePath, NULL, self.bounds);

self.textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), mutablePath, NULL);

CGPathRelease(mutablePath);
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

And the analyzer is pointing at the last line `CFRelease(framesetter)` and saying "Potential leak of an object".

Does anyone how to fix this and why I'm seeing this only in xCode5?

Comment: You have _two_ calls to Core Foundation with `Create` in their name. You have to `CFRelease` both. Xcode 5 is apparently better at analyzing the code and finding the leaks than prior versions.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks again. Yeah that's good to know xCode5 has improved in that regard, not sure how my code wasn't crashing this is pretty glaring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a framesetter and never free it

```
self.textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(.....
```

== new object that is CREATED but not freed.

change to:

```
CTFramesetterRef newFrameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(.....
self.textFrame = newFramesetter;
if(newFramesetter) CFRelease(newFrameSetter);
```

---

as for why only xcode 5 : because it offers more warnings than before. It has been improved in that regard I'd guess

Answer (score 0):

@Dauh-Djan

but will it cause exc_bad_address problem on self.textFrame?

```
self.mAttributeString = [self fixLastLineMissBugWhenDrawWithCoreText:self.mAttributeString];


CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)self.mAttributeString);

CGSize size = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, self.mAttributeString.length), NULL, CGSizeMake(self.widthLimit, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
self.height = size.height + 0.5;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.widthLimit, self.height));
NSUInteger length = self.mAttributeString.length;

CTFrameRef ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, length), path, NULL);
self.ctFrame = ctFrame;

CFRelease(ctFrame);
CGPathRelease(path);
CFRelease(frameSetter);
```

it solve the `Potential leak of an object` warning, however it will cause `self.ctFrame` to an exc_bad_address problem...